# Unexpected integration variable, what does it mean?

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently came across an integral that has an unexpected integration variable (not your regular dx).  A shortened example is below where "A" are some constants that don't involve $\Theta$.  Since I have never seen this before I have several questions: Is there a special name for this form, how would I solve such a thing in quadrature and how do you perform the actual integration?

$y = \int_0^\pi A \cdot d[cos^2(\Theta/2)]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation is very common in applied sciences, specially in physics. It means what it seems, even if it seems strange: your variable is $\cos^{2}(\theta/2)$. Let me give you an example that ilustrates in what context it rises: suppose $A$ is a constant and we have to evaluate the integral $$\int A \frac{d\cos^{2}(\frac{\theta}{2})}{d\theta}d\theta$$
Then, physicists usually write this integral as $$A \int  d\cos^{2}(\theta/2) = A cos^{2}(\theta/2) $$
In other words, it is as you if were considering the derivative $\frac{d\cos^{2}(\theta/2)}{d\theta}$ as a fraction, and you could "cancel" the $d\theta$ factors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Let me see if I understand this, there really is no integration then?  Do I evaluate $A cos^2(\Theta/2)$ at the upper and lower bounds like I would a normal integration?  Just trying to figure out how to use this equation.

Comment: Actually, there is an integration but with respect to the "strange variable" $\cos^{2}(\theta/2)$. If you had the integration variable $x$, then $\int A dx$ would give $Ax$. If $x$ is "replaced" by $cos^{2}(\theta/2)$ then $\int A d\cos^{2}(\theta/2) = A \cos^{2}(\theta/2)$.